# Como quitar el filtro en una JTable

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una tabla en la cual necesito filtrar algunos datos, esto lo hago con un combobox, para filtrar me sale bien, pero al momento de seleccionar el item del index 0 (default) no me devuelve la tabla a su estado normal, que hago?

Uso este codigo.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == this.jCarreras) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                int index = this.jCarreras.getSelectedIndex();
                String item = (String) (this.jCarreras.getSelectedItem());
                if (index > 0) {


                    this.sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(item, 5));

                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Como puedo hacer para que cuando el index sea 0, me devuelva toda la información de la tabla original?

Comment: Estimado, puedes compartir el codigo del Jtable tambien... eso ayudaría

Answer (score 0):

Ya que el problema no está en el combobox, sino en la tabla... habitualmente el Jtable se usa con DefaultTableModel.... por lo que la tabla solo cambia su de manera visual, no de datos propiamente tal ...

Por ende en la tabla deberias tener algo así....

```
   DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tblDatos.getModel();
    int selectRowIndex = tblDatos.getSelectedRow();
    if (selectRowIndex >= 0) {
        idMuestras = (int) modelo.getValueAt(selectRowIndex, 0);
```

donde modelo.getvalue deberias cambiar por el tblDatos.getValue